# Rails Devise-omniauth route points to passthru instead of twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, twitter-oauth, omniauth

I am trying to implement `omniauth-twitter` with Devise in Ruby-on-Rails with no success.
According to the [definitive article of Devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview), the link

```rb
<%= link_to "Sign up with twitter", user_twitter_omniauth_authorize_path,
    method: :post %>
```

should take the visitor to Twitter (Note I have disabled `turbo` site-wide with `Turbo.session.drive = false` and so `turbo` is irrelevant).

However, it just displays

> Not found. Authentication passthru.

I notice the route looks wrong in the first place:

```bash
% bin/rails routes -g omni
                          Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                             Controller#Action
user_twitter_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /users/auth/twitter(.:format)          users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru
 user_twitter_omniauth_callback GET|POST /users/auth/twitter/callback(.:format) users/omniauth_callbacks#twitter
```

It apparently points to `Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#passthru`, which is a non-existent method, hence the error?

This problem has been reported multiple times in Stackoverflow and Github (e.g., [Github](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/5236%5D), [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427516/omniauth-facebook-with-devise-missing-passthru-errors), [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13812844/3577922)). A general advice seems to be using POST as opposed to GET. However, besides it is definitely POST in my case (as confirmed with a log file), I doubt if it is relevant to the routes!

What is the probable cause of this probblem and how can I solve it?

I confirm I am using OA1 API keys as opposed to Twitter OA2 (the latter is not supported by Omniauth, yet).. Also, as the [doc of omniauth-twitter](https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter#authentication-options) suggests, I confirm that "User authentication set up" is active in the Twitter Dev center to allow users to log in.

My relevant files are as follows:

```rb
 # Gemfile
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise-i18n'
gem 'omniauth', '~> 2.1' #, '1.9.1'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-rails_csrf_protection'
```

```rb
 # /config/initializers/devise.rb
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.omniauth :twitter, 'MY_APP', 'MY_SECRET'
  OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger if Rails.env.development? # for debug
end
```

Note there are no Omniauth or Twitter-related configs in `config/initializers/`. Just `devise.rb`.

```rb
 # /models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, #...snipped...
         :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: %i(twitter)

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    find_or_create_by(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid) do |user|
      user.display_name = auth.info.nickname.strip
      user.skip_confirmation!
    end
  end

end
```

```rb
 # /app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:twitter]

  def twitter
    callback_from __method__
  end

  def callback_from(provider)
    # See User model
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: provider.to_s.capitalize) if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.#{provider.to_s}_data"] = request.env['omniauth.auth'].except(:extra)
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url(from_omniauth_callback: true)
    end
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

```rb
 # /config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, except: [:destroy], 
    controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks' } 
end
```

View (the turbo-part is meaningless, for it is globally turned off).

```rb
 <%# /app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb >
<%= link_to t(".sign_up_with_twitter"), user_twitter_omniauth_authorize_path,
  method: :post, data: { turbo: false } %>
```

The standard output of the server (`bin/dev` in Rail 7):

```
00:... | I, [2022-...6 #793]  INFO -- : Started POST "/en/users/auth/twitter" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-11-27 00:33:14 +0000
00:... | I, [2022-...4 #793]  INFO -- : Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#passthru as HTML
00:... | I, [2022-...0 #793]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "locale"=>"en"}
00:... | D, [2022-...0 #793] DEBUG -- :   Rendering text template
00:... | I, [2022-...7 #793]  INFO -- :   Rendered text template (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 10)
00:... | I, [2022-...9 #793]  INFO -- : Completed 404 Not Found in 4ms (Views: 2.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 1170)
```

#### Version information

- `omniauth-rails_csrf_protection` (0.1.2) → (1.0.1)

  - `Gemfile` did not specify the version and yet a lower-version was installed. I now `bundle install` with `'~> 1.0'`. The same error still remains (after server-restart).
- `omniauth` (2.1.0)
- `omniauth-oauth` (1.2.0)
- `omniauth-twitter` (1.4.0)
- `devise` (4.8.1)
- `rails` (7.0.4)
- `ruby` (3.1.2)

That's it. Thank you.

Comment: Please post your `routes.rb` file.

Comment: `users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru` should be a method provided by the `omniauth-twitter` gem to "pass through" to Twitter URL. [See here](https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter#authentication-options)

Comment: Can you show the POST method happening? Since you turned off Turbo, `method: :post` shouldn't actually do anything. Turbo is what uses `data-method="POST"` to turn a GET request into a POST request.

Comment: @Chiperific I have edited the question to include `routes.rb`, server log, and View. I see, `#passthru` is supposed to "pass through" to Twitter… It seems not working, even though in Twitter Dev center, "*User authentication set up*" is active to allow users to log in.

Comment: Please run `rails routes` and post output, just the omniauth portion is fine.

Comment: You have no Omniauth or Twitter configs in your `config/initializers` folder, right?

Comment: And can you confirm that `omniauth-rails_csrf_protection` is upgraded '~> 1.0'

Comment: And make sure your base `oauth` gem is pristine: `bundle update oauth` (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74154377/1880203))

Comment: @Chiperific Omniauth-portion of routes are already included near the top of the post (which points to `passthru`). Sure, no Omniauth initializer is present. Version of `omniauth-rails_csrf_protection` was 0.1.2. It is now explicitly upgraded to 1.0.1, plus `bundle update oauth` was run, which changed nothing. Yet, the error still remains… The question is edited to reflect these and also to include other versions. Perplexing…

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a full answer, but more of a suggestion of where to keep looking.

You are supposed to see `(twitter) Request phase initiated.` in the logs immediately following `Started POST "/users/auth/twitter"` (from [here](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/5523)).

But, the Omniauth controller is instead looking for an HTML template to render (and failing to find one).

```rb
INFO -- : Started POST "/en/users/auth/twitter" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-11-27 00:33:14 +0000
INFO -- : Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#passthru as HTML
INFO -- :   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "locale"=>"en"}
DEBUG -- :   Rendering text template #<--- HERE!!!!
INFO -- :   Rendered text template (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 10)
INFO -- : Completed 404 Not Found in 4ms (Views: 2.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 1170)
```

This does make sense; because `Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#passthru` is getting the POST request as HTML, it's looking for an HTML template to render (and failing to find one).

It seems like Omniauth expects an AJAX request as JSON, not an HTML request.

A few thoughts:

- Turn Turbo back on and see what the `content-type` of the request is when Turbo gets to decide
- Ditch the `user_twitter_omniauth_authorize_path` in favor of intercepting the link click and forming an AJAX POST request using Stimulus (Rails 7) or Javascript directly to the path `/users/auth/twitter`.
- The language "en" in the URL of the POST is probably coming from some other gem (`devise-i18n`?) That could be interfering with the POST request somehow and turning the content-type to HTML instead of JSON.

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer. I now understand the fact a HTML template is looked for is wrong… though "why" is yet to figure out… Turning Turbo back on resulted in the same, as far as the log is concerned (providing I was doing right – my knowledge of Turbo is limited). The locale in the URL is from the URL-param/path-based polity in [Rails standard I18n](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-url-params). Devise is fully I18n-compatible. I am not sure about OmniAuth now…